# ASP.net Custom error page redirect fails when error occurs in webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have custom error page  for a webservice.  The custom error page is displayed properly in test environment. The same fails in production environment, a 'Runtime Error' page displays showing how to setup CustomErrors.

I have the following pieace of code in Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="WebServiceError.aspx"/>
```

I have the following code in webserviceerror.aspx

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>");
Response.Write("<WebServiceError>");
Response.Write("<ErrorCode>9999</ErrorCode>");
Response.Write("<ErrorDescription>Errore Tecnico</ErrorDescription>");
Response.Write("</WebServiceError>");
```

1) i am able to open WebServiceError.aspx without any issues from browser.

2) i have tried with a html file WebServiceError.html , this also fails

3)i have tried mentioning absoulte and relative paths for refering webserviceerror.aspx in web.config

4) I have checked that the web.config file is proper and not having any issues.

I have been not able to find the solution for long time now, Please Help.

Thanks in advance,

Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

A few points that come to mind:

You should *always* include the path to your error page in the `<customErrors>` tag.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/myErrorPageFolder/WebServiceError.aspx">
```

The `mode="RemoteOnly"` attribute tells IIS that you only want to see the custom error pages when requesting the page from a machine other than the one that is hosting the site. If you're running the browser and web server on the same box (typical when debugging using the VS web server or a local IIS instance), you won't see your custom error page.

If there are any errors in your `webServiceError.aspx`, it won't work correctly.

How are you calling the web service? Have you tried looking at the request and response in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: Hi David, The weserviceerror.aspx is working properly, i am able to view the page from IE. The error page(webserviceerror.aspx) and web.config are in the same folder, so i havent mentioned the path. Please help.

Comment: @Pradeep it doesn't matter if the error page and web.config are in the same folder. You still need a path. Look at the request in Fiddler and update your question with the results. That's the fastest way to diagnose the issue. Also, you haven't commented on any of the other suggestions.